# "got" vs. "have got"

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, present-tense

> Reg: What's that you ***have got*** Meggie?
>
> Reg: Show us.
>
> Meggie: No, she's mine! ***I got*** her for my birthday!
>
> Reg: We just want to have a look.

Reg used the present perfect *have got* in the first sentence; instead, Meggie used the past tense *got*.

If Meggie used *have got*, would the sentence be correct?

Comment: You're fine in US English, where *have got* is a present-tense form meaning *possess*, whereas *got* is a past-tense form meaning *obtained*; present perfect is not employed in referring to a specifically dated past event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be incorrect for Meggie to use *have got* instead of *got*, both semantically and grammatically.  First, note that when Reg says  “What's that you have got?”,  he means “What do you have?”, or  “What are you holding?”.  On the other hand, when Meggie says *got* she means *received*.  Second, Meggie could grammatically (but wordily) say “I have gotten her for my birthday”. In this context, “I have got her for my birthday” seems wrong to my American ear.

Regarding American English vs British, if I heard  “What's that you have got?” I'd imagine the speaker to be using BE. From an AE speaker I would expect to hear any of  “What have you got?”,  “What've you got?”,  “What do you have there?”, “What is it you've got there?”, “What's that you've got there?”, etc, ie *you* after *have* in some cases; *have* without *got*; a filler *there*; different contractions.

Comment: Both "gotten" and "got" are past participles of the verb "get",I found in google Dictioanry,if “I have gotten her for my birthday” is correct then why "have got" is wrong.

Comment: @amishAa: British English - got is past participle of get; American English - gotten is past participle. BUT in American English "have got" = "have" with more emphasis on possession. Whereas "have gotten" = "have obtained."

Comment: One would not use "have got" in BrE **for a single thing received at one time**. In BrE and AmE, if you received a present, it would be: I got it for my birthday.

Answer (score 0):

*Have*, and *have got* mean "to own, hold or possess something."

> He had a new car and a boat.
>   Have you got a job yet?

*Get* means "to receive something; to obtain something."

The answer given by Meggie is perfectly fine, and I would understand it as "I obtained her for my birthday."

Answer (score -3):

Another discussion from ELU https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/difference-between-i-have-got-and-i-have-gotten

In my opinion, its usage is too complicated for a word that can often be substituted with a better one. Also the spoken usage sounds strange or incorrect in some cases.

So rather than say

> What's that you have **got** Meggie?
>   and
>   No, she's mine! I **got** her for my birthday!

why not say

> What's that you have **received** Meggie?
>   and
>   No, she's mine! I **received** her for my birthday!