# What is the difference between "have" and "have got"?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I am confused between the following sentences:

> I ***have*** a pen. and
>
> I ***have got*** a pen.

What is the difference between them?

Comment: One might once have been British English (I have) vs American English (I have got) but to my mind they're interchangeable in modern usage and both can be heard around the world.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: [“got” vs. “have got”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/4856/3281) or [“I have” vs “I have got”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/62943/3281)

Comment: Yes, the are mostly interchangeable. But if I *forcefully* get into the nuance, 'got' shows some 'efforts'.

Comment: I don't think *have got* shows effort.

Answer (score 1):

Have and have got mean the same thing. You can normally use either form.  However, have got is more informal.